# Why VLC can't open my USB camera but zoom can? (In windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, usb, vlc-media-player

When trying to open my usb camera with VLC I get

```
Capture failed:
The device you selected cannot be used, because its type is not supported.
Capture failed:
VLC cannot open ANY capture device. Check the error log for details.
Capture failed:
The device you selected cannot be used, because its type is not supported.
Capture failed:
VLC cannot open ANY capture device. Check the error log for details.
```

But the strange thing is that zoom can open it without issue.

I am running the latest vlc version 3.0.12

Logging is apparently disabled by default
I enabled it by going to

```
Tools -> Preferences -> Select "ALL" -> Advanced -> Logging
```

Checking in the log did not reveal anything helpful, except that it's "directshow" that can't open this camera

```
dshow error: can't use device: USB CAMERA, unsupported device type
```

I increased the log level to debug, but this did not reveal much more

dshow debug: dshow-vdev: USB CAMERA
dshow debug: found device: USB CAMERA

I tried to find the USB ID and I am not sure I got it right but it might be

```
USB\VID_0AC8&PID_3420\5&22ac01e1&0&3
```

[image: This is what the camera looks like]

This is a usb or hdmi output camera with a c-mount, it is used as a microscope camera but I'm using it as a normal webcam that has interchangeable lens.

Thanks !

Comment: Open the source menu (`Ctrl+C`). On the `Capture Device` tab in the `Select Device` window, select your camera. If you do not see your camera there or specified any arbitrary name - the VLS does not support your model. Perhaps you need a driver from the manufacturer. In the question, you must specify the manufacturer and camera model.

Comment: The camera is there called "USB CAMERA" zoom can open it so no driver is needed. I suspect this is "directshow" related issue but ... ?

Comment: find another program that will see your camera. VLC is not suitable

Comment: As stated in the title, I already have one of those and this is not what I'm asking.

Answer (score -1):

This is almost certainly because the resolution is too high, wrong, or the usb bus doesn't support the throughput (especially if you're using a usb 2 hub).

You need to run `v4l2-ctl --all` this should show you all of your devices now that work in vlc then run `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` this should show you a list of devices something like this,

```
Integrated Camera: Integrated C (usbid):
    /dev/video2
    /dev/video3
    /dev/video4
    /dev/video5
    /dev/media0
    /dev/media1

UC70: UC70 (usbid):
    /dev/video6
    /dev/video7
    /dev/media2
```

Find the video* device you want. In this case UC70 is my webcam which exposes two device /dev/video6 and /dev/video7.

Then find the formats they support like this

```
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video6 --list-formats-ext
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video7 --list-formats-ext
```

For me, only `video6` has any supported formats and it returns this (note you want the video stream not MJPG),

```
    [1]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
        Size: Discrete 1920x1080
            Interval: Discrete 0.500s (2.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 3840x2160
            Interval: Discrete 1.000s (1.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1280x720
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.500s (2.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 2048x1536
            Interval: Discrete 0.500s (2.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 2560x1440
            Interval: Discrete 0.500s (2.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 640x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.500s (2.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 1.000s (1.000 fps)
```

Now before doing anything I can cross check what vlc defaults to by running `vlc v4l2:///dev/video6 -vv` in that I see this,

```
[00007f1b64001170] v4l2 demux debug:  best discrete frame size: 3840x2160
[00007f1b5c000c30] lua art finder debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
[00007f1b5c000c30] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
[00007f1b5c000c30] main art finder debug: no art finder modules matched
[0000563402032240] qt interface debug: IM: Setting an input
[00007f1b64001170] v4l2 demux warning: cannot reset cropping limits: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[00007f1b64001170] v4l2 demux debug: 16588800 bytes maximum for complete image
[00007f1b64001170] v4l2 demux debug: Interlacing setting: progressive
[00007f1b64001170] v4l2 demux debug: color primaries: 8
[00007f1b64001170] v4l2 demux debug: transfer function: 1
[00007f1b64001170] v4l2 demux debug: YCbCr encoding: 1
[00007f1b64001170] v4l2 demux debug: quantization: 0
[00007f1b64001170] v4l2 demux debug: added new video ES YUY2 3840x2160 (3840x2160)
[00007f1b64001170] v4l2 demux debug:  frame rate: 1/1
[00007f1b64001170] v4l2 demux debug:  aspect ratio: 1/1
[00007f1b70000c90] main input debug: selecting program id=0
libv4l2: error turning on stream: Input/output error
[00007f1b64001170] v4l2 demux error: cannot start streaming: Input/output error
[00007f1b64001170] v4l2 demux debug: opening device '/dev/video6'
[00007f1b64001170] v4l2 demux debug: device UC70: UC70 using driver uvcvideo (version 6.1.27) on usb-0000:52:00.0-2.2.2.2
[00007f1b64001170] v4l2 demux debug:  with capabilities 0x05200001 (overall 0x85A00001)
[00007f1b64001170] v4l2 demux error: not a radio tuner device
```

Let's try a different resolution that is not 3840x2160

```
vlc v4l2:///dev/video6 -vv --v4l2-width=640 --v4l2-height=470
```

works fine.

tldr; VLC opens the highest resolution stream, zoom and other clients do not.